# JBoss factory-injection and methodcall

Tags: hibernate, dependency-injection, jndi, jboss6.x

i use *@JndiInject(jndiName="xxx")* on an private Field named "sessionFactory" of type *org.hibernate.SessionFactory* - this works great!

How do i inject an concrete *org.hibernate.Session* (long-lifed)?

```
@JndiInject(jndiName="xxx")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private Session hibernateSession session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

will create an NPE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [@PostConstruct](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) annotation to execute any kind of logic after all dependencies are injected:

```
@PostConstruct
private void initSession() {
  session = sessionFactory.openSession();
}
```

Comment: Finally i use PersistenceContext instead of JndiInject